# При сохранении выборки из SQL в xlsx, выдает ошибку MemoryError

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

Пытаюсь выгрузить выборку из бд SQL, в которой 180 столбцов, в .xlsx. Выдает ошибку 'MemoryError'. Пользуюсь средствами Pandas, максимально получалось сохранить в файл 5000 строк, если пытаться выгрузить более - выдает эту ошибку. Подскажите как можно это разрешить, хотелось бы вытащить около 100000 строк.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import os

workdirectory = 'C:\\Users\\user\\'


def MY_database_selection(query,
                          sql_driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
                          sql_database='NOVSM2010',
                          sql_server='nserver',
                          sql_login='login',
                          sql_password='password',
                          writetoexlsx=False,
                          namexlsx='Selection'):

    sql_connection = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={sql_driver};"
                                    f"DATABASE={sql_database};"
                                    f"SERVER={sql_server};"
                                    f"UID={sql_login};"
                                    f"PWD={sql_password}")
    sql_query = query
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, sql_connection)
    sql_connection.close
    if writetoexlsx:
        global workdirectory
        count = 0
        while True:
            if f'{namexlsx}{count}.xlsx' not in os.listdir(workdirectory):
                df.to_excel(f'{workdirectory}{namexlsx}{count}.xlsx')
                print(f'Создан файл {workdirectory}{namexlsx}{count}.xlsx')
                break
            count += 1
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MY_database_selection(query="SELECT TOP(100000) * From tablica", writetoexlsx=TRUE, namexlsx='proba')
# MemoryError



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kozlovs01/PycharmProjects/srochnoproject/Database.py", line 51, in <module>
    "WHERE Clients.ID = Dogovor.ID_CLIENT", writetoexlsx=True, namexlsx='proba')
  File "C:/Users/kozlovs01/PycharmProjects/srochnoproject/Database.py", line 41, in MY_database_selection
    df.to_excel(f'{workdirectory}{namexlsx}{count}.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1766, in to_excel
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 654, in write
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1018, in save
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 390, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 284, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 83, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 203, in _write_worksheets
    xml = ws._write()
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 893, in _write
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 108, in write_worksheet
    write_rows(xf, ws)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\etree_worksheet.py", line 38, in write_rows
    write_row(xf, worksheet, row, row_idx, max_column)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\etree_worksheet.py", line 58, in write_row
    el = write_cell(xf, worksheet, cell, cell.has_style)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\etree_worksheet.py", line 102, in etree_write_cell
    cell_content.text = safe_string(value)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\strings.py", line 34, in safe_string
    value = "%.16g" % value
MemoryError
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст error traceback

Answer (score 0):

В общем, надо просто сохранять в csv с разделителем ';' и тогда проблем не случается, вроде.

```
workdirectory = 'C:\\Users\\user\\'
df.to_csv(f'{workdirectory}123.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```